# Is PS4 Manual Eject Screw supposed to tighten

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, hardware

My PS4 works fine 9/10 of the time, but at some point, usually ingame or at night, it will eject the disc in it (if any) and then the ejection engine will start spinning like crazy and the console will triple beep repeatedly.

It seems to go away for a while (a day, usually) if I unplug the PS4 and try to turn it on several times, but sometimes it doesn't work and I have to resort to other methods. On the web I found "remove rubber foot", tried, didn't change a thing.

Eventually, on Sony's site, I found "tighten manual eject screw" I did that and it seemed to work, for a while, after which the PS4 had the issue again. I did it again and it only worked for a shorter time before "screwing up" again.

One thing I noticed is that the screw **does not actually tighten**. Instead, it spins infinitely. I have never overtightened the screw, damaged or modified my PS4 or even done anything weird with my PS4.
Online, other users too seem to have had this problem.

Sony refuses to repair the PS4 out of warranty and, for the same price as a new slim, wants to give me an old refurbished PS4 with only 6 months warranty. I am totally **not** going to do this nor buy another PS4: I only play on PS4 for the few exclusives as I have switched to PC. What I'd like to know is if it is normal for the "screw" to be like this (which means my problem cannot be solved) or if maybe I could have the screw replaced by a third party and maybe my issue could be solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue about a month after I bought my console. I tried everything, same as you; adjusted that rubber foot, twisted that internal screw, but nothing helped. If memory serves, that screw will not actually tighten, or at least I did not have the patience to see if it would. The solutions you have found online do work for some people, but in my case (and I'm guessing yours), a replacement was needed.

Unfortunately, you're out on a warranty, and a refurb isn't quite worth it in my opinion. The only recommendation I can make is to maybe [get a base for the PS4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H3S1B5A) so that it can sit on its side, taking pressure off the rubber foot and disc-eject sensor. I used this for a long time until my setup needed the PS4 in a different spot for WiFi connectivity.

Otherwise, it may be best to wait for a sale to get a new PS4 for cheaper than a refurbished device.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a PS4 with the same issue. Their solution was to actually disengage the button itself. And just use the menu eject.